# How can I pass MySQL functions as bind parameters in prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, perl, bind, dbi

I'm trying to do this:

```
$sth = $dbi->prepare('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute(
    $var1,
    $var2 || 'NOW()',
    $var3
);
```

without any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$sth = $dbi->prepare('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, COALESCE(?, NOW()), ?)');
$sth->execute(
    $var1,
    $var2,
    $var3
);
```

Comment: +1: clever. I always forget about coalesce. I didn't even know it would work in this context.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. If only I could set a default value for 'datetime' columns.

Comment: Note that `coalesce` is really equivalent to `//`, not `||`.  However, it may be good enough for what you're doing, if `$var2` never contains the empty string or 0.

Answer (score 3):

Functions cannot be bound parameters. MySQL will enclose them in quotes which is not valid syntax.

Your options are:

- DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - If the field is a TIMESTAMP field you can declare it to have a default of the current time like this. This does not work for DATETIME fields.
- Use perl - `$now = time2str('%Y-%m-%d %T', time);`

Comment: You've got to be kidding... Working out the date string for yourself doesn't require you to change languages. The first thing to mind is `use Date::Format; $now = time2str('%Y-%m-%d %T', time);`, but there's probably a quicker/easier way to do it out there that I've forgotten about.

Comment: @Dave: Ah, you know I somehow missed completely that this was a Perl question, and not a PHP question. The syntax is so similar. I'll update my question to match your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following coding also.

```
$sth = $dbi->prepare('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, COALESCE(?, NOW()), ?)');
$sth->bind_param($var1,$var2,$var3); 
$sth1=$sth->execute;
```